# Chart x-axis maximum value not being set correctly

Tags: c#, charts, windows-forms-designer

I currently have a chart on my C# Windows Form Application (in Visual Studio 2013) that gradually draws a line onto it using a timer. I have tried to set the minimum and maximum values for the x- and y-axes and although the y-axis values are being set correctly and appearing as expected on the chart, the x-axis range is not being set correctly and stops at a certain point (around 17.9). Here is the code for the chart and the timer that I currently have:

```
private void btnPlotGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = double.Parse(txtTotalHorizontalDistance.Text);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0 - double.Parse(txtInitialHeight.Text);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = double.Parse(txtTotalVerticalDistance.Text);
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] xCoordinates = File.ReadAllLines("H:\\Computing Coursework\\Code\\FormPrototype\\testX.txt");
    string[] yCoordinates = File.ReadAllLines("H:\\Computing Coursework\\Code\\FormPrototype\\testY.txt");

    chart1.Series["Projectile1"].Points.AddXY(xCoordinates[i], yCoordinates[i]);

    if (i >= xCoordinates.Length - 1)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also, here is a screenshot of the form once it is run to show the problem with the x-axis maximum value (which should be 81.08 as shown in the text box):

[image]

Comment: Your fault is in the x-values. As you add them as string their values __all are 0__ so you can't do anything with them except displaying them in the default labels. No formatting, no ranges.. - Make sure to convert them to a number!! - Note: If the strings contain valid numbers the y-values do get converted but the x-values don't..

Comment: Btw: Do you really want to read the files all over again? Or are they changing..???

Comment: @TaW The contents of the files change each time the program is run so I need to re-read them each time. I'm not sure that it's a problem with the values being strings because even if I replace the line that reads the text boxes with an integer value, i.e. 'chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 82;' the program still does not work correctly.

Comment: Well I am sure, but I am talking about the X-Values, not the Min&Max ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fault is in the x-values.

As you add them as strings their values all are `0` so you can't do anything with them except displaying them in the default labels. No formatting, no ranges..

Make sure to convert them to a number, maybe like this:

```
 string[] xStringCoordinates = File.ReadAllLines(yourFileName);
 double[] xCoordinates = xStringCoordinates.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToArray();
```

Note: If the strings contain valid numbers the y-values do get converted by the system but the x-values don't..